# Using purely polymorphism and inheritence to call functions on a derived class from base class without casting?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

My problem is:
I have a card game, it consists of Minions, Spells and Equipment which are all types of Card, I am aware of virtual definitions for methods. I need to use the `GetHealth()`, `RemoveHealth()` and `AddHealth()` functions on a `Minion` but I do not want these on a `Spell` or `Equipment`. What I wish to do is this:

```
class CCard
{
//Member variables and functions
};

class CMinion : public CCard
{
    //Member variables and functions
    int GetHealth() const {return mHealth;}
};

std::unique_ptr<CCard> minion = std::make_unique<CMinion>(params);
minion->GetHealth(); //I realize this isn’t possible the way it is.
```

I currently have a separate list of minions with and ID associated to a card, when the card is in my hand, I instead put the Minion object on the table rather than the card. My lecturer wants **pure polymorphism and inheritance** so this is a clumsy solution. 
I also discussed putting `GetHealth()` and the other required methods in the Card class and making the classes that don't need it return 0. He said "This is a better solution, but again I should employ inheritence and polymorphism".

He recon's my architecture is wrong and i should restructure it.

I should have:
A vector of cards being an instance of `Minion`, `Spell`, or `Equipment`. The table, hand and deck should be all vectors of cards but my current solution is the deck and hand are vectors of cards and my table is a vector of Minions.

Can anyone come up with a better structure or efficient solution?

Comment: Make `GetHealth` a pure virtual member function of `CCard`

Comment: @acraig5075: `GetHealth` doesn't make sense for `Spell`/`Equipment`...

Comment: Note: manual memory management is not "simpler" in any way, actual code is fine.

Comment: @acraig5075: Sorry i wasnt specific, when i said "I also discussed putting GetHealth() and the other required methods in the Card class" - I meant putting a pure virtual GetHealth() in the Card class. My lecturer was not too fond of that as seen further on.

Comment: No operation that makes sense for more than one type but must be implemented differently for each type => no case for polymorphism, your lecturer's desires notwithstanding.

Comment: Are `Minion`, `Spell` and `Equipment` are really needed to be `Card`? As it seems card only "invoke" one of those, which will then be placed specifically from there type.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes they do, he want us to have a vector of cards, minion, spell and equipment must all derive from the card class  "since they ARE a type of card" he said.

Comment: Is there any operation, anything, that is common to all types of card? You then should make it a virtual function of CCard. What can you do with *any* card?

Comment: @NikosC. That was a typo, "C" before class names is the naming convention my lecturer wanted me to go with. Edited to fit example.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes I do, i have a pure virtual method called "Activate()" which is mandatory for when a card is played. A spell is cast in "Activate()". A minion attacks another minon or player in "Activate()". To attack another minion i also need that minion's health and need to be able to remove it. That's about it for commonalities asside from the cards non-virtual / protected fields and methods.

Comment: How do you know you attack a `Minion` and not a `Spell` or `Equipment`? Do you need [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) (or maybe just [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern))?

Comment: So a minion can attack another minion but not a different type of card right? How does it choose a minion to attack?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m.: The parameters for all "Activate" methods consists of the enemy player, the enemy minion, the other player and their minions. I have a deck of cards and a list of minions linked by an ID. When I play a minion of type "CCard" it will instead take an actual minion of type "CMinion" from the minion list and place it on the table. Hence spells and equipment targets only minions which are on the table or the players. My lecturer doesn't like this solution.

Comment: @Jarod42: I haven't heard of a double dispatch but I will attempt to implement it from the example of the comment below.

Comment: So you have a list of cards and a separate list of minions, right? And the table only contains minions, right?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m.: Yes, precisely.

Comment: So you only take things to attack from the table. The table only contains minions. The type is known. There is no need to cast, and no need to double dispatch.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.That would be problem solved however my lecturer told me to change it so that everything is handled with card's, including the table. What I have told you just now is my current soltuion which works but not tailored to the lecturers liking. I need to change it as he says it is too inefficient.

Comment: This requirement doesn't seem justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jarod42 in his comment to the original question, you can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

This allows you to get the actual type of a `Card` object without any casts. It's also known as double dispatch.

This then allows you to put functions specific to a certain type of card in only that card's type. I.e. no need to put a default virtual `GetHealth ()` function in `Card` that throws an exception. Just declare a `GetHealth()` function in the `Minions` card type, `Spell` won't have `GetHealth()`.

Here's a small example:

```
// Forward declare visitors so Accept function can be delared in Card.
struct CardVisitor;
struct ConstCardVisitor;

struct Card {
  virtual ~Card () = default;

  virtual void Activate () = 0;

  virtual void Accept (CardVisitor & obj) = 0;
  virtual void Accept (ConstCardVisitor & obj) const = 0;
};

// Forward declare derived Card types, so Visit function can be declared in visitors.
struct Minion;
struct Spell;

struct CardVisitor {
  virtual void Visit (Minion & obj) = 0;
  virtual void Visit (Spell & obj) = 0;
};

struct CardVisitor {
  virtual void Visit (Minion const & obj) = 0;
  virtual void Visit (Spell const & obj) = 0;
};

struct Minion : Card {
  int GetHealth () const;

  virtual void Activate () override;

  // Copy-paste exactly this code in every "final" type deriving from Card.
  virtual void Accept (CardVisitor & obj) override { obj.Visit(*this); }
  virtual void Accept (ConstCardVisitor & obj) const override { obj.Visit(*this); }
}

struct Spell : Card {
  int GetSmokeColor () const;
  bool DoesInstaKill () const;

  virtual void Activate () override;

  // Copy-paste exactly this code in every "final" type deriving from Card.
  virtual void Accept (CardVisitor & obj) override { obj.Visit(*this); }
  virtual void Accept (ConstCardVisitor & obj) const override { obj.Visit(*this); }
}
```

Then create a visitor that does whatever is required. E.g. let's print some info about cards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct PrintVisitor : ConstCardVisitor {
  virtual void Visit (Minion const & obj) override {
    std::cout << "health: " << obj.GetHealth();
  }

  virtual void Visit (Spell const & obj) override {
    std::cout << "smoke color: " << obj.GetSmokeColor()
      << ", does insta kill: " << obj.DoesInstaKill();
  }
}

int main () {
  // Base class pointers, i.e. to Card.
  std::unique_ptr<Card> cardA = std::make_unique<Minion>();
  std::unique_ptr<Card> cardB = std::make_unique<Spell>();

  PrintVisitor printVisitor;
  cardA->accept(printVisitor);
  cardB->accept(printVisitor);
};
```

PS: The destructor of `Card` should be virtual. It isn't in your example code. In which case your derived objects won't be correctly deleted when you call delete on a `Card` pointer (or when `std::unique_ptr` does it for you).

*Edit*: Added `Spell` class to make advantage of visitor pattern a bit clearer.

Comment: This would work, however for the three methods GetHealth(), RemoveHealth() and AddHealth() - I would need to add 3 of these "Accepts" to each deriving class minimum which would be fine. But my Spell class will also have this, even though i could leave it empty in spell (because spell doesnt need it), wouldnt this work the exact same way if i put GetHealth(), RemoveHealth() and AddHealth() in my card class as a virtual method and make them empty in spell as well? It just seems like a lot less effort for the same result, unless i am missing the point?

Comment: I'll extended the example with a `Spell` class. The point is that you add `GetHealth()` only those those classes for which it makes sense. You do indeed need to implement `Accept()` for each derived class. The key thing is though, that in each implementation `Accept()` calls `Visit()` with the actual object's type as argument, i.e. the type of the argument to `Visit()` will never be `Card &`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I see how this would work to my advantage, but other than the health and the Activate method each of them have, there is no difference between Minion, Spell an Equipment class. That said, I will definitely refer back to this solution if my classes each have something that I would like to call but do not want to put in the base class. A very useful method. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
class Card
{
public:
    virtual ~Card() = default;

    template <typename T>
    T* As() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(this); }
};

class Minion : public Card
{
public:
    int GetHealth() const {return mHealth;}

private:
    int mHealth = 100;
};

void test()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Card> card = std::make_unique<Minion>();
    if (auto* minion = card->As<Minion>())
        minion->GetHealth();
}
```

The `if (auto* minion = ...` part is a compact way to check if the type is `Minion` and also get a pointer to it so you can call methods that do not exist in the base class.

Comment: It says no cast in the title, this includes all cast's whether it is dynamic_cast, static_cast or any other cast. Lecturer says he doesn't want that.

Comment: @XenoXetric You probably misunderstood something in the assignment. It is impossible to call a member function that only exists in a subclass through a base class reference or pointer without casting.

Comment: @NikosC. It's perfectly possible by using a visitor pattern (see Jarod42's comment to original question). No need for casts.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put `GetHealth` in `Card`, or use casting later on. No other way. Since casting is out of the question, that means `Card` needs `GetHealth`.

To avoid casting, you can store the card type as a data member in `Card` and use a non-virtual `type()` function. The constructors of the various card type classes would then construct their `Card` part using the appropriate type.

To prevent stand-alone construction of base card classes like `Card`, `Minion` etc and only allow actual cards to be created (like `Goblin`, `Armor`, etc), make the type-specifying constructors protected:

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum class Type { Minion, Spell, Equipment };

    virtual ~Card() = default;
    Type type() const { return type_; }
    virtual int GetHealth() const { return 0; }

protected:
    explicit Card(const Type type) { type_ = type; }

private:
    Type type_;
};

class Minion : public Card
{
public:
    int GetHealth() const override { return mHealth; }

protected:
    Minion() : Card(Type::Minion) { }

private:
    int mHealth = 100;
};

class Goblin : public Minion
{ };

class Equipment : public Card
{
protected:
    Equipment() : Card(Type::Equipment) { }
};

class Armor : public Equipment
{ };

void test(Card& card)
{
    if (card.type() == Card::Type::Minion) {
        std::cout << "Health: " << card.GetHealth() << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not a minion.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Goblin goblin;
    Armor armor;
    test(goblin);
    test(armor);
}
```